# application running on iOS crashes

Tags: ios, javafx, gluon

I am adopting a JavaFX application for iOS using java 8 and gluon / roboVM. After a lot of struggling I managed to get it running on the iPad Simulator but unfortunately the compiled app crashes. Now I am in need of some ideas how to figure out what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

I tried adding to forceLinkClasses controlsfx, but this does not work. As you can see I added step by step a lot things via forceLinkClasses:

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
    }
    }

    apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()

        jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
    compile 'de.myapp.app:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'org.slf4j.**.*',
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'com.google.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*',
                'dev.rico.**.*',
                'de.myapp.app.**.*',
                'com.github.rodionmoiseev.**.*',
                'com.jfoenix.**.*',
                'org.controlsfx.**.*',
                'com.sun.javafx.**.',
                'controlsfx**',
        ]
    }
}


    ./gradlew clean launchIPadSimulator --refresh-dependencies
    Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
    The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.

> Task :GluonMobile-SingleViewProjectApp:compileIosJava 
Note: /Users/joerg/Projekte/sprouts/GluonMobile-SingleViewProject/GluonMobile-SingleViewProjectApp/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/sources/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/ios/BasicLauncher.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/joerg/Projekte/sprouts/GluonMobile-SingleViewProject/GluonMobile-SingleViewProjectApp/build/javafxports/tmp/ios/sources/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/ios/BasicLauncher.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :GluonMobile-SingleViewProjectApp:launchIPadSimulator 
Root pattern javax.annotations.**.* matches no classes
Root pattern controlsfx** matches no classes
Warning: java.awt.image.BufferedImage is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Image is a phantom class!
Warning: javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.PopupMenu is a phantom class!
Warning: java.awt.Point is a phantom class!
Warning: javax.swing.JMenuBar is a phantom class!

    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory=com.sun.xml.stream.events.ZephyrEvent...
    java.vendor.url=http://www.robovm.org/
    java.ext.dirs=
    line.separator=

file.encoding=UTF-8
java.runtime.version=0.9
user.name=mobile
java.compiler=
prism.static.libraries=true
android.icu.unicode.version=6.2
javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrWriterFactory
java.version=0
android.icu.library.version=51.1.0.1
os.arch=x86_64
java.io.tmpdir=/Users/joerg/Library/Developer/CoreSi...
glass.platform=ios
android.zlib.version=1.2.8
user.language=en
java.vm.version=2.3.5-SNAPSHOT
com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true
javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.sun.xml.stream.ZephyrParserFactory
path.separator=:
java.runtime.name=RoboVM Runtime
java.specification.version=0.9
user.dir=/Users/joerg/Library/Developer/CoreSi...
java.vm.specification.vendor=RoboVM
java.vm.name=RoboVM
java.vm.specification.version=0.9
prism.useNativeIIO=false
user.home=/Users/joerg/Library/Developer/CoreSi...
jfxmedia.platforms=IOSPlatform
java.specification.name=RoboVM Core Library
file.separator=/
user.variant=
os.version=10.14.3
java.boot.class.path=/Users/joerg/Library/Developer/CoreSi...
java.vm.specification.name=RoboVM Virtual Machine Specification
javafx.platform=ios
user.region=US
os.name=iOS Simulator
java.class.path=/Users/joerg/Library/Developer/CoreSi...
prism.verbose=true
java.specification.vendor=RoboVM
java.vm.vendor=RoboVM
prism.mintexturesize=16
prism.allowhidpi=true
java.vendor=RoboVM
android.icu.cldr.version=23.0
android.openssl.version=OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
java.home=/Users/joerg/Library/Developer/CoreSi...
java.vm.vendor.url=http://www.robovm.org/
java.class.version=50.0
Prism pipeline init order: es2 
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Using system sized mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
        succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.IOSGLFactory
IOSWindowSystemInterface : share 0 view 0 pf otready 
GL_VERSION string = OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-17.0.37
GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 0.0
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
  initialize() returns 140294095934848
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
IOSWindowSystemInterface : share 285c3e0 view 0 pf otready 
GL_VERSION string = OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-17.0.37
GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 0.0
CTXINFO vendor
CTXINFO renderer
CTXINFO glExtensions
CTXINFO GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
CTXINFO allocate the structure
CTXINFO set function pointers
Attributes = onScreen: trueredSize : 8, greenSize : 8, blueSize : 8, alphaSize : 8, depthSize : 24, doubleBuffer : true
  initialize() returns 140294099043712
IOSWindowSystemInterface : share 285c3e0 view 0 pf otready 
GL_VERSION string = OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-17.0.37
GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 0.0
CTXINFO vendor
CTXINFO renderer
CTXINFO glExtensions
CTXINFO GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
CTXINFO allocate the structure
CTXINFO set function pointers
Attributes = onScreen: trueredSize : 8, greenSize : 8, blueSize : 8, alphaSize : 8, depthSize : 24, doubleBuffer : true
  initialize() returns 140294095947936
Maximum supported texture size: 4096
Non power of two texture support = false
Maximum number of vertex attributes = 16
Maximum number of uniform vertex components = 512
Maximum number of uniform fragment components = 256
Maximum number of varying components = 32
Maximum number of texture units usable in a vertex shader = 8
Maximum number of texture units usable in a fragment shader = 8
Graphics Vendor: Apple Inc.
       Renderer: Apple Software Renderer
        Version: OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-17.0.37
 vsync: true vpipe: true
AAAAAAA1
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'javax.servlet.Servlet'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>javax.servlet.Servlet</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'org.slf4j.ext.EventData'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>org.slf4j.ext.EventData</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.

  ____________________________________________________________________________________
  |   _____  _                  __                                           _       |
  |  |  __ \(_)                / _| _ _  __ _  _ __   ___ __ __ __ ___  _ _ | |__    |
  |  | |__) |_  ___ ___       |  _|| '_|/ _` || '  \ / -_)\ V  V // _ \| '_|| / /    |
  |  |  _  /| |/ __/ _ \      | |  |_|  \__,_||_|_|_|\___| \_/\_/ \___/|_|  | \ \    |
  |  | | \ \| | (_| (_) |     | |                                           | |\ \   |
  |  |_|  \_\_|\___\___/      |_|  Version $version | by dev.karakun.com    |_| \_\  |
  |__________________________________________________________________________________|


[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'org.slf4j.ext.EventData'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>org.slf4j.ext.EventData</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'org.slf4j.ext.EventData'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>org.slf4j.ext.EventData</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'org.slf4j.ext.EventData'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>org.slf4j.ext.EventData</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'org.slf4j.ext.EventData'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>org.slf4j.ext.EventData</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
AAAAAAA2
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.font.t2k.T2KFactory'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.font.t2k.T2KFactory</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
2019-03-07 17:01:50.526 GluonMobile-SingleViewProjectApp[8524:941891] Done creating private storage /Users/joerg/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B9A4EAA3-3F23-4EBC-9C08-08CD4180ECBA/data/Containers/Data/Application/F496D07F-DB90-4A86-BE14-2BB9E5EE8F0A/Library/gluon
HELL!!!_3a
HELL!!!_4
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'de.myapp.app.office.login.login_en_US'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>de.myapp.app.office.login.login_en_US</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'de.myapp.app.office.login.login_en'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>de.myapp.app.office.login.login_en</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'de.myapp.app.office.login.login'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>de.myapp.app.office.login.login</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
bbbb1
HELL!!!_3a
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'controlsfx_en_US'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>controlsfx_en_US</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'controlsfx_en'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>controlsfx_en</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'controlsfx'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>controlsfx</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
HELL!!!_5
AAAAAAA3
AAAAAAA4
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle_en_US'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle_en_US</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle_en'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle_en</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecorder'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.oracle.jrockit.jfr.FlightRecorder</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_en_US'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_en_US</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_en'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls_en</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.resources.controls</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 31s
8 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Comment: And where is the exception? Anyway ControlsFX (and probably JFoenix) won't work on iOS with Java 8, because of the use of Streams and other non supported methods. You should try first a simple project without these dependencies. Note as well that you could make it work on 9 with GluonVM...

Comment: @JoséPereda That's the problem, I can't find an exception. Only a message similar to  "App crashed with sigint ..." in the logging of the iPad Simulator. I have tried a simple project and that worked out good :-) But thank you for the hint with ControlsFX and Streams. I will give GluonVM a try.